# Setting value in componet is slow in android s1 APP

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, android

```
var start = new Date();
component.set("v.isLoading", false);
window.alert(new Date() - start);
```

The execution time of above line(excluding the timer) is 180 ms on the desktop while it is taking approximately 1150 ms second on an s1 APP of android tablet.

Execution of any instruction on the Android S1 app is 5-10 times slower than desktop/IPAD.
Is there any way to optimize this?